# regular expression

Tags: formal-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Construction of a regular expression](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/construction-of-a-regular-expression)

can someone help me with the following exercise?
In the formation of a regular expression from a finite automaton $A$ with three states they have been calculated the following parts, in which 1,2 and 3 been renamed, 1 is the start state and 2,3 are accepting states:
$L^2 _{1,1} = b^*(aab^*)^*$
$L^2 _{1,2} = b^*a(ab^*a)^*$
$L^2 _{1,3} = b^*a(ab^*a)^*b$
$L^2 _{3,2} = b^*ba(ab^*a)^*$
$L^2 _{3,3} = |\epsilon|a|b^*ba(ab^*a)^*b$
And now the question is to perform the remaining construction of a regular expression for $L(A)$

i already tried this exercise with nerode but i didnt come to a solution please help me
thank you guys

Comment: There seems to be information missing from the question. Also just saying "Tried with Nerode" doesn't say very much.

Comment: im new here please forgive

Comment: i dont know how to solve this i read everything but i didnt come to an answer

Comment: [Exercise 5.3.c](http://www.tks.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/teaching/ss12/th-inf-2#exercises), due May 24th.